# findviewbyid() is returning null on larger android device but not on smaller devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

i have a game for android. When my game is installed on a 4,7 inches tablet with android 4.4.2, the game is fine and don´t crash. When it´s played at a 10 inches tablet with android 4.1.2, the game crashes with a warning of nullpointerexception on a findviewbyid() calling. I debbuged it and saw that the system can´t find my Button "botaoitenscompeticao" on the view.

Did someone already have this problem? How to solve it?
I am not calling it on OnCreate()
I am not using a Dialog box or something. It´s the normal View

Comment: Do you have the same layout for mentioned devices?

Comment: thank you. Sorry for that ;)

Comment: I see you have edited your question but did not provide the answer to mine :) By asking if you have the same layout for both devices I was interested in whether or not the activity/fragment/view you are mentioning is the same for 4.7" tablet and 10" tablet(say they reside in layout-xhdpi and layout-sw-620dp etc.)

Answer (score 0):

i was using different layouts for different devices. Sorry